# Combine two select queries from one table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have mysql table with structure like

```
id | first_id | second_id
 1 |        1 |         2
 2 |        1 |         4
 3 |        1 |         9
 4 |        4 |         6
 5 |        5 |         9
 6 |        9 |        10
```

I want to get list of ids that are in one pair with **x**:

Each pair of ids represents relationship between 2 objects. So I want to get all ids of objects that have relations with object **x**.

```
SELECT first_id 
  FROM Table 
 where second_id = x 
  JOIN SELECT second_id 
         FROM Table 
        where first_id = x
```

This query return syntax error for some reason - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your expected out put ?

Comment: it is list of ids

Comment: A lot. The WHERE clause comes after the JOINS. Lookup the MySQL SELECT statement for syntax. Joins use an on clause, not a where with from clause.

Comment: i think this is you want SELECT first_id as id FROM Table where second_id = x 
union
SELECT second_id as id FROM Table where first_id = x

Comment: Really not sure what the aim is. Is it to get rows from the table where either the first_id or the second_id equals 'x' ? Or do you want to find the records where the first_id of one is equal to the second_id of another? Your 'in one paid with x' is not clear.

Comment: each pair of ids represents relationship between 2 objects. So all that I want is to get all ids of objects that have relations with object x.

Comment: try this SELECT * FROM Table where (second_id = x && first_id = x)

Comment: JYoThI, why &&? and Also i won't receive list of ids

Comment: replace && with or and try again @moonvader

Comment: i still don't get list of ids

Comment: can you please show table with sample data @moonvader

Comment: @JYoThI - i added example to question

Comment: what is your expected output from above sample data ?

Comment: if x = 1 i expect (2,4,9) and if x = 9 i expect (1, 10)

Comment: did yo tried this SELECT first_id as id FROM Table where second_id = x union SELECT second_id as id FROM Table where first_id = x

Comment: did you try it for demo data? I have different output

Comment: @moonvader Why just `(1,10)` for `x=9`. There is a relation between `first_id =5` and `second_id=9`. So even `5` should come, right?

Comment: Sorry, you are right - it must be (1, 5, 10) if x = 9

Comment: SELECT first_id as id FROM testing where second_id = '9' union all SELECT second_id as id FROM testing where first_id = '9'   its giving (1,5,10)

Comment: use union all instead of union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will check the x value with both second_id as well as first_id and get the  first_id and second_id  respectively.

```
SELECT first_id as Id
FROM Table 
WHERE second_id = x 
UNION ALL 
SELECT second_id 
FROM Table 
WHERE first_id = x
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
SELECT 
    a.`id` as `id`,
    a.`first_id` as `first_id`,
    b.`first_id` as `related_id`
FROM Table a
JOIN Table b
ON a.`first_id` = b.`second_id`
WHERE a.`first_id` = x
```

Comment: not working because Table a and b - is the same table

Comment: That's the two table in your query. If you have different tables, you have to put that in your question.

Comment: Care to share the error? Kinda important since that tells you what is wrong.

Comment: Your question is unclear at best. You need to provide an example of what you want returned, the schema of the table and the relationship of the results.